# UPDATE an SQLite datetime field with fractional seconds

Tags: datetime, sqlite

I'm synchronizing historical data between two systems and I've found a small clock problem between their logs.

I've loaded the data into an SqlLite and need one of the sets by a small amount (~40 milliseconds).  However, I'm unable to do so as it seems to always round the time to the nearest second.

For example, attempting something like the following

`UPDATE my_table SET my_datetime = DATETIME(my_datetime, '+0.04 seconds')` rounds up to the nearest second and I can't find any fractional/millisecond modifier option.

Is there a way to do this that I'm overlooking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite hasn't a type for datetime. See http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Using `datetime(...)` you are storing your dates as strings. This is equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)`.

One option is to use a strftime with fractions of seconds:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_datetime = STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f',my_datetime, '+0.04 seconds')
```

Comment: Perfect.  Quick warning to folks that for some reason you have to add an additional millisecond to make it work.